# Error while adding google signin lib in react native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-signin

I'm working on login into AWS through Google, but while adding the google sign in library I'm getting an error.

> C:\Users\krishna21\Awsslogin\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
>                                ^
>
> C:\Users\krishna21\Awsslogin\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
>                                    ^
>
> C:\Users\krishna21\Awsslogin\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\Utils.java:4: error:
>   package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

I have added

```
npm install --save react-native-google-signin
```

this library I'm running the app through

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
```

I think you're using androidx which had a huge change in support packages:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings

Comment: @alishaxyz Why did you run it without jetifier? Jetifier can fix these kinds of issues. It will go through your node modules and change any packages that use old packages that were used before the android X migration. In the mean time you'd just have to wait for the package to get android X support

Comment: ok, My error is resolved can you please recomemend me what should i do or which link i should follow to login into AWS through google

Comment: You'd have to make a new thread for that or google it. If your fix was different from my answer please post it as an answer so people can find it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try using AWS Amplify, which is far superior in features and its been tested for security and errors.
In AWS Federated Login can be done in 2 ways, one using Cognito User Pool as well as using Cognito Identity Pool. 
Please add the Google Client ID in Edit identity pool->Authentication providers->Google+
Whitelist the domain which you are hitting in Google Developer account.
Full documention is here https://itnext.io/google-sign-in-using-aws-amplify-and-amazon-cognito-69cc3bf219ad

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-adds-authentication-features-and-enhancements-for-ios-and-android-mobile-sdks/